# mockito unit test cases for Response entity performing HTTP GET request

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I am writing unit test cases for one of my methods which performs GET Request(query to external system), and receives query results which i store in my model object, I am not able to mock the rest template exchange. Need some help with it.

The below code includes my method and also my test class for the method.

```
public Car getCarModelDetails(String id) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Accept", APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers);
    ResponseEntity<QueryResultCar> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(
            config.restUrl + "/v" + config.restVersion + /query?q=SELECT + SELECT_COLUMNS
                    + " FROM Car WHERE (Model = '" + id + "')",
            HttpMethod.GET, entity, QueryResultCar.class);

    if (exchange.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
        List<Car> records = exchange.getBody().records;
        if (records != null && records.size() == 1) {
            return records.get(0);
        } else (records == null || records.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } 

    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}


private static class QueryResultCar extends QueryResult<Car> {
}

  @Test
public void getCarModelDetails_valid() throws JSONException {   
    String id = null;
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers);
     new ResponseEntity<>("", HttpStatus.OK);
    Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(config.restUrl + "/v" + config.restVersion + /query?q=SELECT + SELECT_COLUMNS
                    + " FROM Car WHERE (Model = '" + id + "'), HttpMethod.GET, entity, QueryResultCar.class))
            .thenReturn(response);  

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use matchers and probably need to use verify and and arg captor to check all the things you want. I would probably divide this test up because it has many assertions, but this should get you started.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SubjectTest {

@InjectMocks
private CarCar subject;
@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Test
public void getCarModelDetails_valid() throws JSONException {
    String id = "123";
    Config config = new Config();
    when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString(), eq(HttpMethod.GET), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(QueryResultCar.class)))
            .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(new QueryResultCar(), HttpStatus.OK));

    Car actual = subject.getCarModelDetails(id);

    ArgumentCaptor<HttpEntity> httpEntityArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(HttpEntity.class);
    verify(restTemplate).exchange(eq(config.restUrl + "/v" + config.restVersion + "/query?q=SELECT + SELECT_COLUMNS"
            + " FROM Car WHERE (Model = '" + id + "')"), eq(HttpMethod.GET), httpEntityArgumentCaptor.capture(), eq(QueryResultCar.class));
    assertEquals(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, httpEntityArgumentCaptor.getValue().getHeaders().get("Accept").get(0));
    assertEquals("Car to string", actual.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you paste the test execution result here?

Comment: Thanks a ton DCTID, this helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Object reference of "entity" in your unit test method and real method is different. You need to handle mock for "entity"